# How to fix a buffer to a pane

Tags: buffers, window

I have my emacs in 2 by 2 configuration. When debugging, certain actions triggered the opening of another file. The newly opened file could be in a specific window pane and covers originally opened file in that pane. Is it possible to anchor or fix a buffer in a specific window pane. So whenever a new file is opened, the file in that window pane remains on top of the buf

Comment: Select the window of that buffer and try `M-: (set-window-dedicated-p (selected-window) t)`. Does it what you want?

Comment: @Tobias Yes, it is doing what I want. Thanks a lot!